# Parse a String using Parsec?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I am trying to parse a String using parsec in Haskell, however every attempt throws another type of error.

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
csvFile = endBy line eol
line = sepBy cell (char ',')
cell = many (noneOf ",\n")
eol = char '\n'

parseCSV :: String -> Either ParseError [[String]]
parseCSV input = parse csvFile "(unknown)" input
```

This code, when run through stack ghci produces an error saying "non type-variable argument in the constraint: Text.Parsec.Prim.Stream"

Basically, I am wondering what the most straight forward way to parse a String into tokens based on commas is in Haskell. It seems like a very straightforward concept and I assumed that it would be a great learning experience, but so far it has produced nothing but errors.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with all the imports, extensions, etc. you are using.

Comment: Apologies, added the import to the code above. I am running this on ghci

Comment: Thank you. I ran this on `stack ghci` and it worked fine. I also tried `parseCSV "test\n"` which correctly produced `Right [["test"]]`. I'm using GHCi 8.4.3, but I don't think it should matter much. I wonder what could go wrong for you, but your code looks fine here.

Comment: I don't get any problems when putting this in a file like `tmp.hs` and running `:l tmp` in GHCi (version 8.0.2). Possibly a monomorphism restriction issue, depending on how you are actually entering this in GHCi, due to the lack of explicit type signatures for the combinators.

Comment: A minimal example: `eol = char '\n'` produces the error, but `:t char '\n'` can return a (constrained) type.

Answer (score 1):

The error I see when entering `char '\n'` in ghci is:

```
<interactive>:4:1: error:
• Non type-variable argument
    in the constraint: Text.Parsec.Prim.Stream s m Char
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
• When checking the inferred type
    it :: forall s (m :: * -> *) u.
          Text.Parsec.Prim.Stream s m Char =>
          Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m Char
```

The advice about `FlexibleContexts` is accurate.  You can turn on `FlexibleContexts` like so:

```
*Main> :set -XFlexibleContexts
```

Unfortunately, the next error is `• No instance for (Show (Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s0 u0 m0 Char))` (basically, we can't print a function) so you'll still need to apply the parser to some input to actually run it.

Like commenters, I find that `parseCSV` can be used without any language extensions.

There are a few things going on here:

- In the context of the whole program, the type of `eol` is constrained by the type signature on `parseCSV`.  That doesn't happen when typing `eol = char '\n'` into GHCi.
- GHCi's `:t` is permissive - it's willing to print some types that use language features that aren't turned on.
- GHC has grown by adding a large number of [language extensions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html), which can be turned on by the programmer on a per-module basis.  Some are widely used by production-ready libraries, others are new & experimental.